# C# "saving html" in memory

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am using a webBrowser in C# that hosts a html file. But I have to create a file (uri)in order for the webBrowser to run the html. Is there anyway to "save" the html in memory, so the webBrowser can call the html in the program memory. I have some javascript that goes to anchors elements so the filepath changes ie nameoffile.html#a1 to nameoffile.html#a2. Is there anyway to to upload the html to a webBrowser in memory and have the javascirpt run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
var htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
```